# What is a good way to find a specific value in an XML document using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, searching-xml

I'm calling a WebService exposed by Oracle that accepts an input of an ItemID and returns to me the corresponding Item Number. I want to grab the Item Number that has been returned out of the XML contained in the response.

The XML looks like this:

```
<env:Envelope
  xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:ns0="http://dev1/MyWebService1.wsdl">
 <env:Header>
  <wsse:Security
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    env:mustUnderstand="1"/>
 </env:Header>
 <env:Body>
  <ns0:getItemNbrByItemIdResponseElement>
   <ns0:result>1010603</ns0:result>
  </ns0:getItemNbrByItemIdResponseElement>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I'm interested in grabbing only the `<ns0:result>1010603</ns0:result>` particularly only the 1010603.

I haven't done a lot of work parsing XML using C# and I'm playing around with a few different methods so far. What is the recommended way to do this?

I'm on VS2008 (so XPath is available etc.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd personally use LINQ to XML, because I find that easier to deal with than XPath, particularly when namespaces are involved. You'd do something like:

```
XNamespace ns0 = "http://dev1/MyWebService1.wsdl";

String result = doc.Descendants(ns0 + "result").First().Value;
```

Note that `doc` here is expected to be an [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345449.aspx), *not* an [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx). (My guess is that this is why it wasn't showing up for you.)

Comment: Agreed; without LINQ you'd need to use namespace-managers and all sorts - this is much simpler.

Comment: +1, namespaces "need" to be easier to work with which XLINQ does nicely

Comment: When trying to use this VS is complaining about the .Descendants method. Despite having using System.Linq and System.Xml.Linq present. Any thoughts/what I'm missing? I certainly like how concise this solution is.

Comment: @Jon - Yep that fixed up the issue there. Now just figuring out why it's stating that the sequence contains no elements. :) Thanks again for the fix!

Comment: I needed to use an XMLNodeReader in order to properly populate the XDocument, that's all. Now it works like a champ. Thanks again Jon.

Answer (score 5):

fwiw you can cheat the namespace issue with an xpath like this: `//*[local-name()='result']`

Comment: this is much more elegant than the chosen Answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to go for Linq you could use XPathDocument to retrieve the value:

```
XPathDocument xmldoc = new XPathDocument(@"C:\tmp\sample.xml");
XPathNavigator nav = xmldoc.CreateNavigator();

XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("ns0", "http://dev1/MyWebService1.wsdl");

XPathNavigator result = nav.SelectSingleNode("//ns0:result", nsMgr);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result.Value);
```

XPathDocument has a lower memory footprint and is most likely faster in your scenario than XmlDocument. XmlDocument builds up a complete object model of your XML document in memory whereas XPathDocument does not do that.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, the following should work:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;

XmlNamespaceManager mgr = GetNamespace(doc);
doc.LoadXml(xmltext);

XmlNode nd = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//ns0:result", mgr);
```

The namespace code looks like this:

```
private XmlNamespaceManager GetNamespace(XmlDocument document)
{
    XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
    mgr.AddNamespace("ns0", "http://dev1/MyWebService1.wsdl");
    return mgr;
}
```

You need to use the namespace manager because the XML document has namespaces associated with it, and XPath uses this in query resolution.

Comment: That's close... Just tried it out and it's giving me an error: 

Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

Comment: My bad - the SelectSingleNode should have a reference to the namespace manager with it. I'll update it.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! :) I could just step-up my game and learn a few things and then you wouldn't have to solve my problems for me! ;)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, I used Jon Skeet's answer. Here's the code that I had to implement to make this work (for anyone else's future benefit).

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

XNamespace ns0 = "http://dev1/MyWebService1.wsdl";

xmlDoc.Load(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc));                          

String result = xDoc.Descendants(ns0 + "result").First().Value;
```

This of course assumes I'm getting my response back from an HttpWebRequest named **request**.

Answer (score 0):

There are very good and complete answers to this question.

I'd add **just out of curiosity, that an extremely simple XPath expression does the job** in this particular case:

**`normalize-space(/)`**

This is easily done in C# using something like the two lines below:

```
        XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

        string res = (string)navigator.Evaluate("normalize-space(/)");
```

With the good optimization of the .NET XPath engine, its evaluation may even be efficient.